# addView() to inflateLayout

Tags: android, inflate

Here my Code:

```
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(TabAndPlay.this, R.layout.current_play, null);

        TextView tv = new TextView(TabAndPlay.this);
        tv.setText("hallo");
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        ll.addView(tv);
```

current_play.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/aktuelle_spiele"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

R.id.llPlay (there xml shows so)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llPlay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the onOptionsItemSelected()

```
        case R.id.current_play:
            LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llPlay);
            mainLayout.removeAllViews();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.current_play, mainLayout, true); 
            return true;
```

If i click on my menu item, all my current views on R.id.llPlays are removed!
The button from current_play is shown. But the TextView from "Here my code" dont show..
Why? Whre is my error?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous so I will guess an answer:

In your `onOptionsItemSelected()` you search for the `LinearLayout` with the id `R.id.llPlay` and remove all the child views from it with `removeAllViews()` and then inflate the `R.layout.current_play` and aspect your layout to have the `LinearLayout` (`aktuelle_spiele`) with the `Button`  but also the `TextView`(for which you set the text "Hallo"). The problem is that when you inflate a layout you inflate only the views that are on that layout at that moment. If you want your layout to also contain that `TextView` that you build in code then you have 2 options:

1 Add the `TextView` directly in the `current_play.xml` layout and also add an id to it so you can later retrieve that `TextView`(whith `findViewById(R.id.the_text)`) and set the text to "Hallo":

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/aktuelle_spiele"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/the_text" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit:**

2 Then build the layouts dynamically where you want but hold a reference to that inflated view. So, if you create a view like this:

```
 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(TabAndPlay.this, R.layout.current_play, null);
        TextView tv = new TextView(TabAndPlay.this);
        tv.setText("hallo");
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        ll.addView(tv);
```

then hold the reference to that inflated view `ll` and pass it in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` callback to the main layout:

```
case R.id.current_play:
            LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llPlay);
            mainLayout.removeAllViews();
            mainLayout.add(ll);
            return true;
```

Comment: Thanks, but directly in the current_play dont get because i get dynamic textviews. I like to create one or more layouts dynamicly (which isnt display) and if the user select the menu (R.id.current_play) than i want to show the layout that i have createt bevor..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the layout params for that textview.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wrap_content,wrap_content);
```

Then while adding

```
ll.addView(tv);
```